# Keeping Android device awake

Tags: android, libgdx, gui, touch, user-experience

I currently program a game in which the user don't need to interact with the screen. Is there any way to keep the screen awake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use a [wake lock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html). Example from the docs:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
wl.acquire();

// screen and CPU will stay awake during this section

wl.release();
```

I've got this answer from [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3723649/5185376). For detailed information go there.